# According to Common Core standards, what math skills are beginning Kindergarteners supposed to have?

Tags: primary-education, common-core

I remember looking once at what chikdren in Kindergarten were expected to know, and it was quite a bit. I have a young son, and would like to know:

What is a Kindergartener expected to know about numbers and shapes and other mathematical concepts?

Comment: basic differential geometry

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From http://www.corestandards.org/Math/Content/K/introduction/:

**Counting and Cardinality**

- Know number names and the count sequence.
- Count to tell the number of objects.
- Compare numbers.

**Operations and Algebraic Thinking**

- Understand addition as putting together and adding to, and understand subtraction as taking apart and taking from.

**Number and Operations in Base Ten**

- Work with numbers 11-19 to gain foundations for place value.

**Measurement and Data**

- Describe and compare measurable attributes.
- Classify objects and count the number of objects in each category

**Geometry**

- Identify and describe shapes.
- Analyze, compare, create, and compose shapes.

**Mathematical Practices**

- Make sense of problems and persevere in solving them.
- Reason abstractly and quantitatively.
- Construct viable arguments and critique the reasoning of others.
- Model with mathematics.
- Use appropriate tools strategically.
- Attend to precision.
- Look for and make use of structure.
- Look for and express regularity in repeated reasoning.

Answer (score 4):

http://www.corestandards.org/Math/Content/K/introduction/

I am not aware of *incoming* requirements for Kindergarten but the link above details the learning goals for CC math at grade K.

Comment: May I suggest that you make the answer more self-contained by summarizing how the link answers the question.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a github page that details connections between **all** standards: **[CCSSM Flow View](http://jeffbaumes.github.io/standards/)**

For example, you can hover over the standards for **K** and see how they relate to others. Moreover, you can click through to see the description of the standard, its prerequisites, and its dependent strands.

Site description:

> Hover over a standard to see what it depends on (blue) and what depends on it (red). The colors fade as the dependency chain to the standard becomes longer. Click on a standard for more detail on the standard and its prerequisites and dependent standards. The dependencies are derived from a [shared spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AtYMTchBa3Y2dEpIUHpudlRfbWs0eGY1TTJ1ZE01UXc#gid=0), referenced from a [document](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/11459286/ccssmgraph.pdf) by Jason Zimba.

Hopefully this helps clarify both what is to be known for CCSSM, and also how the covered material will be built upon in subsequent years.